# C++ Getting undefined symbol error

Tags: c++

I am trying to do an assignment  and the program compiles fine on my home
PC (Netbeans) but when I try and compile on the Uni Sun box I get the following error

compile flags : g++ -lm -ansi -Wall -pedantic skyhigh.cpp -o skyhigh

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
Flight::GetSeats()                  /var/tmp//cc49OAwj.o
Flight::GetCost()                   /var/tmp//cc49OAwj.o
Flight::GetAircraft()               /var/tmp//cc49OAwj.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to skyhigh
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,as I have spent hours combing the internet
for the solution

FLIGHT.H File

```
        //
// flight.h
//
// Parent Flight class
//

#ifndef __FLIGHT_H__
#define __FLIGHT_H__

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
/*TO DO  REQUIRED HEADER FILES AND NAMESPACES*/


class Flight
{

protected:

   string aircraft;
   string category;
   int seats;
   double cost;




public:
   virtual ~Flight(){};

  // virtual void Display() =0;
   void SetAircraftType(string air);
  string GetAircraft();
  int GetSeats();
  double GetCost();
  void SetSeats(int seat);





 //TO DO
  // Prototypes of all the Item functions

};

#endif


FLIGHT.CPP FILE


        #include "flight.h"



 string Flight::GetAircraft(){

    return aircraft;

 }
 int Flight::GetSeats(){


    return seats;
 }

 double Flight::GetCost(){


    return cost;
 }
 void Flight::SetSeats(int seat){

    seats=seat;

 }
void Flight::SetAircraftType(string category){


   aircraft = category;
}


MAIN FILE

// skyhigh.cpp for CPT 323 Assignment 1 SP3 2013
//
//
// CPT323 2013  assignment 1



#include "skyhigh.h"


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
   Flight newflight ;

   cout<< "Plane Name:" <<newflight.GetAircraft()<< " Seats: "<< newflight.GetSeats()<<"Cost: "<<newflight.GetCost()<< endl;


   Scenic newflight2 ;

  //cout<< "Plane Name:" <<newflight2.GetAircraft()<< " Seats: "<< newflight2.GetSeats()<<"Cost: "<<newflight2.GetCost()<< endl;

  //Scenic* sptr=&newflight2;

  //BookingSheet booking;

  //cout<< booking.GetDay()<<booking.GetTime()<<booking.GetPassengerName()<<booking.GetPaymentStatus()<<endl;

   int finished = 0;  

   do {
      /*Create array for use in menu options*/




   cout << "Main Menu : " <<endl;
   cout << "1) Add a flight booking "<<endl;
   cout << "2) Remove a flight booking "<<endl;
   cout << "3) View current booking sheet " <<endl;
   cout << "0) Exit \n" <<endl;

  cout<< "Please make a selection (0-3) ";


  int selection;
  cin>> selection;

  /*Capture user selection default in switch statement validates 1-9*/
//   fgets(option,sizeof(option),stdin);
// 
// 
   switch (selection) {
       case 0: 

        cout << "Thanks for using the SkyHigh Booking System"<<endl;

        finished=1;
           break;
        case 1: 

        cout << "1) Add a flight booking "<<endl;


           break;
        case 2:

         cout << "2) Add Customer "<<endl;

            break;


      case 3:

         cout << "3) Display Stock " <<endl;

           break;


        default:
            printf("Valid input is 0-3 \n");

    }

    }
   while(!finished);


return 0;
}
```

MakeFile

```
skyhigh: skyhigh.o utility1.o flight.o scenic.o aerobatic.o
    g++ skyhigh.o utility1.o flight.o scenic.o aerobatic.o -o skyhigh

skyhigh.o: skyhigh.cpp skyhigh.h flight.h aerobatic.h scenic.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -pedantic -gstabs -c skyhigh.cpp

utility1.o: utility1.cpp utility1.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -pedantic -gstabs -c utility1.cpp

flight.o: flight.cpp flight.h aerobatic.h scenic.h
    g++ -ansi -Wall -pedantic -gstabs -c flight.cpp

scenic.o: scenic.cpp scenic.h 
    g++ -ansi -Wall -pedantic -gstabs -c scenic.cpp

aerobatic.o: aerobatic.cpp aerobatic.h 
    g++ -ansi -Wall -pedantic -gstabs -c aerobatic.cpp



clean:
    rm -f *.o core *.report *.errs
```

Comment: Of course you get missing symbols, you don't link with all needed files. If you have a makefile, *use it*, don't compile by hand.

Comment: where is the constructor ?

Comment: @ Jachim Pileborg..you are spot on ..as soon as I read that I knew what I was doing wrong. just use the make command and all is good. Thank You

Comment: Don't use underscores and capitals in your header guards. These are implementation-reserved and makes them dangerous to use!

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the object file where those missing functions are defined. Make sure you are adding the generated object file for linking. Something like that (main is the exec name and main.o is the object with the main function, change them as needed):

```
g++ -o main main.o skyhigh.o utility1.o flight.o scenic.o aerobatic.o
```